# Assembly language + moving values to and from registers

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a question about X-86 or IA32 assembly language(not really sure if there the same my textbook seems to use them interchangeably) I have the following code that is supposed to perform the following operation

Move the current value(stack address) of `%ebp` into a register add `0x20` to it then store the result "inside" the current value of `%ebp`. This is the code I have basically it calculates the frame pointer of the previous stack frame which by actual calculations using GDB is `%ebp + 0x20`.  Could anyone please tell what I am missing?

```
movl %ebp, %edx   //move the "stack address" of %ebp into the register
addl $0x20, %edx  // add 0x20 to the value in %edx which is actually the address of the stack of %ebp
movl %edx, (%ebp) //overwrite the contents of %ebp with our calculated values from the previous 2 steps
```

Also when I say "stack address", I don't mean `%esp` the stack pointer. I mean the memory address of that location on the stack instead of the value contained in it (if that makes sense).

Comment: stack address is in `%esp` stach pointer not `%ebp` base pointer

Comment: It seems to be correct. What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: Basically my program just segfaults I am assuming due to the fact that the calculation is not being performed the way I think my code does it

Comment: Are you saving/restoring registers before using them?

Comment: `movl %edx, (%ebp) //overwrite the contents of %ebp`.  This comment is wrong.  You're overwriting the memory pointed to by `%ebp`.  Anyway, downvoted for being totally unclear.  No clue what the OP is trying to do with the address of the caller's saved `%ebp`, or what they hope to accomplish by storing that value to `(%ebp)` (which holds this stack frame's saved `%ebp` value, i.e. our caller's ebp, in a function that uses ebp as a frame pointer.)

Answer (score 1):

```
movl %ebp, %edx   
addl $0x20, %edx  
movl %edx, (%ebp)
```

first line, moves the 32 bit value of ebp to edx, you stated that its a stack address, it is not, but it can be, meaning, ebp can point to a stack address only if you put the value of esp into it,

second line adds 0x20 to edx, and edx is overwritten with the sum, more like edx=edx+0x20 in C

Third line moves the sum, from previous line to the 32 bit memory address pointed by EBP, so meaning whatever value of the memory location of pointed by EBP, it is overwritten with 32 bit value of EDX. so thats it.